# How to use substring and how to break down one variable into two variables?

Tags: c#, substring

I have been struggling to solve my problem when i used substring.

**C# :**

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
```

What i want to :

- remove "{", "receipt:" and "}" using substring
- then break down sInput into new two variables such as:

**from :**

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
```

**to:**

```
string sMeal = "vegetable lasgane";
string sReceipt= "cheese sauce etc...";
```

How to do this in C#? Your code example would be much apprecaited. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods like this;

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
string sMeal = sInput.Substring(0, sInput.IndexOf('{'));
Console.WriteLine(sMeal);
//vegetable lasgane 

string sReceipt = sInput.Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ');
sReceipt = sReceipt.Substring(sReceipt.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(sReceipt); 
//cheese sauce etc...
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/kf8slu).

Comment: no, he just wanted he's vote to be picked... i got downvote with no comment too. here, have my +1 cus' your answer is good and you shouldn't get a downvote by a troll

Comment: @Downvoter: Try to add some comments if you downvote or else nobody knows whats wrong with the answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
string[] splitString = sInput.Split('{');
string firstString = splitString[0];
string secondString = splitString[1].Replace("}", "").Split(':')[1];
```

should probably do the trick.

Comment: this does not solve the problem and looks a lot like mine and soner answer

Comment: How does this not solve the issue?
He asked for a c# example.
I didn't notice your answers when I wrote this one, sorry if it offended you somehow mate.

Comment: your answer leaves the "receipt" which he said need to be put out

Comment: Have you noticed the Split(':')[1] at the end? The 'receipt' part is left out.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `Replace()` to remove chars, and `Split("{")` to separate the 2 strings

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
sInput = sInput.Replace("}", "");
sInput = sInput.Replace("receipt:", "");
string[] Parts = sInput.Split('{');
```

and now maybe `Trim()` if needed

```
string sMeal = Parts[0].Trim();
string sReceipt= Parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `value.split("{");`

More examples here :http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 0):

This is not so hard:

```
sMeal = sInput.Split(" { receipt: ")[0];
```

and

```
sReceipt = sInput.Split(" { receipt: ")[1];
sReceipt = sReceipt.Substring(0,sReceipt.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Output:
          Meal: vegetable lasgane
          Receipt: cheese sauce etc...**

```
public void Foo()
{
  int updationIndex = 0; 
  Func<string, char, string> getMyString1 = (givenString, takeTill) =>
         {
            var opString =
                new string(
                    givenString.ToCharArray()
                               .TakeWhile(x => x != takeTill)
                               .ToArray());

            updationIndex = inputString.IndexOf(givenString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                            + opString.Length;

            return opString;
        };

        var smeal = getMyString1(inputString, '{');
        Console.WriteLine("Meal: " + smeal);
        while (updationIndex < inputString.Length)
        {
            var sReceipt = getMyString(inputString.Remove(0, updationIndex), ':', '}');
            Console.WriteLine("sReceipt: "+ sReceipt);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sReceipt))
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
string sInput = "vegetable lasgane { receipt: cheese sauce etc...}";
string one = sInput.Substring(0, sInput.IndexOf("{"));

int start = sInput.IndexOf("{");
int end = sInput.IndexOf("}");
string two = sInput.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);

Response.Write(one + "\n"); // your 1st requirement
Response.Write(two + "\n"); // your 2nd requirement
```